# Logging from within a custom nuget package dependency

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

I am using log4net to log my microservices application.  I have created a nuget package to house some reusable code.

This is my logging declaration in all my classes.

```
protected static readonly ILog Log = LogManager
     .GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Obviously, when I use this declaration inside my nuget package, it creates a log4net logger of my nuget package type.  I lose context of which microservice I am in.

Can I get a logger that reflects the calling method?  Or ideally, as well as the nuget package class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mis-understanding but couldn't you just use [Environment.Stacktrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8) and log the last method outside of your nuget package's namespace?

Comment: Possibly, I'd really like to be able to get both, the nuget class and the calling method.